# Convert Classic Textfield to TFL Textfield dynamically?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, localization, textfield

I have a project which has loads of FLA's with embedded textfields on the timelines. We now need to localize this project into Arabic, with right-to-left text (pulled in from XML) - my understanding is that this is only possible with TLF textfields.

It's going to be a huge task to manually convert all these texfields to TLF. Is there a way to programmatically set a normal textfield to be a TLF textfield?

Comment: Is it mandatory that this happens at runtime? Or could you use an authoring-time (Flash IDE) script that would automate these changes before it compiles it?

Comment: It's not mandatory, no. I dont know how you would make an authoring-time script though? We are using Flash CS5.5.

Comment: Authoring-time scripts would be JSFL, in this case (The Flash IDE JavaScript language)... I'll try to take a look into this for you.

Comment: Would you require that the script traverses each MovieClip, Graphic and Button symbols in the library to convert the classic TextFields to TLF textfields? Or just the ones found on the stage (and the stage's children)?

Comment: Yeah it would have to be every clip both on the stage and also linked in the library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable writing your own JSFL script for this elaborate task, I would recommend that you gain some experience navigating the Flash DOM tree and grab a copy of FriendsofEd's "Extending Flash MX 2004", or at least have a look at its JSFL reference preview PDF: http://www.friendsofed.com/books/1590593049/3049_Ref.pdf . Although this is outdated, the concepts, properties and methods haven't changed significantly (if at all), for the exception of some newer features obviously, TLF textfields being one of'em!

A more complete and updated version can usually be found on the Adobe Livedocs / Help reference online:

- CS3 (PDF)
  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/flash_cs3_extending.pdf
- CS5 (HTML) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7ffa.html

For your specific need, you would have to scan:

- The Main timeline;
- The Main timeline's instances that have timelines (MovieClip, Buttons, Graphics);
- The Library Symbols' timelines;
- The Library Symbols' children's timelines (although, that might be redundant since you're already doing this in a way with the previous
  step;

To scan the current document's timeline for elements, first it's a good idea to store a reference of the current timeline, like so:

```
var doc = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var tl = doc.getTimeline();
```

NOTE: Be aware that this will grab the reference of the currently displayed timeline (whether it'd be a Symbol in "Edit in Place" mode, or another Scene, etc. To make sure it selects your "Main Timeline" anytime you run the script, I believe the following will grab it:

```
var tl = doc.timelines[0]; //Grabs the Main Timeline
```

NOTE: Please correct the above if I'm wrong!

Not fully knowing for certain whether your project has TextFields in different keyframes or if they reside in single-frame timelines, it would make sense to scan each frames of your Timeline to verify the presence of any TextField instances.

To do so though, it is important to note that Instances, or in JSFL terminology "Elements", are not retrievable directly from the Timeline object. You have to dig a bit deeper to get there!

Essentially you must traverse this path:

- The current `Timeline`;
- That `Timeline`'s **layers**;
- Each `Layer` object's **frames**;
- Each `Frame` object's **elements**, then;
- Verify whether it is a `TextField` instance or not;

Once you find those TextFields, it would be a matter of "converting" it to a TLF textfield. Converting, meaning... creating a new TLF textfield, passing all the reusable properties of the classic TextField object to it, placing the TLF textfield at the same index (z-depth) where the classic TextField was, and then discarding it. Optionally you could set all the necessary Embedding and/or TLF properties you need for the Arabic font support.

Without getting into the fine details of how to do this conversion process, you can see that just scanning one Timeline alone is a tough mission. Not impossible, but simply several steps.

If you carefully create your own JSFL functions to encapsulate each necessary steps so that it can be reused in the other necessary scans (other Timelines, Library Symbols, etc.) you will greatly lower the complexity of this task!

Hope that helps you (even though it's not an immediate antidote, as in "Here's the answer, take this..."!)

Comment: It looks like you can't set whether a new textfield created with JSFL is TLF or Classic see here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7f59.html and here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fa4.html :-(

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  You can, of course, create your own class to check each frame, and remove and replace the existing TextFields at runtime (looping through the display list and picking these with `if (timeline.getChildAt(i) is TextField)` should work, although it will probably not improve performance).  But I would advise you not to. Switch to TLF text on your next project, when you don't have to work through tons of existing content.

While using Arabic fonts can be a real hassle - not only does the order of characters have to be reversed, there's also ligatures (a variety of combinations of two or more adjacent characters "merge" to form a more complex symbol); there is almost no way to get this completely right, not even with TLF text - if you're not using input TextFields, [Flaraby](http://www.arabicode.com/) might help you to create a decent version based on your existing classic text.  Be prepared, though - you might have to live with a few trade-offs.

Comment: Preparation is definitely key, especially with multilingual apps / software. It's always a nightmare to be asked right in the middle of a project (or worst, close to its completion) to convert elements of the project that seems to be "an easy task" to the client, but really is a big deal with huge risks of breaking when having to scan through mutliple Flash symbols & timelines to do the conversion. Even automated scripts won't be perfect.